# What is a suspended thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

The `Thread.Abort()` documentation states that it will throw `ThreadStateException` if:

> The thread that is being aborted is currently suspended.

What circumstance is this exactly?

If, for example, the thread is in the middle of a `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, or waiting on a `WaitHandle`, is it considered "suspended"?

Comment: I believe it's referring to the antiquated [`Thread.Suspend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From reading the documentation, it is my interpretation that "suspended" in this context does not relate to the use of `Thread.Sleep` or `WaitHandle` usage, but instead refers to the thread state encountered when using the obsoleted [`Thread.Suspend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx) or equivalent Windows API [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In this context, a suspended thread is a thread whose execution has been explicitly paused (or suspended), i.e. it's context is no longer being executed but has been suspended to be resumed at some later point.

This technique is primarily used by debuggers and is not recommended for sychronization activities. This is clarified in the MSDN documentation on [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This function is primarily designed
>   for use by debuggers. It is not
>   intended to be used for thread
>   synchronization. Calling SuspendThread
>   on a thread that owns a
>   synchronization object, such as a
>   mutex or critical section, can lead to
>   a deadlock if the calling thread tries
>   to obtain a synchronization object
>   owned by a suspended thread.

Comment: So I guess this is your way of saying that ordinary waiting, sleeping, or blocked threads do not count as "suspended". But if a debugger suspends one thread and then another tries to abort it... this could cause an exception?

Comment: @Qwertie: That's my interpretation of the documentation, yes (a debugger or other application that uses the ability to "suspend" threads). I've updated my answer to directly answer your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A suspended thread is one that has suspended due to a call to [`Thread.Suspend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx).

See the [`ThreadState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx) enum for a list of the states a thread can be in and how it gets there.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is rather poor in this regard. `Thread.Abort`, while not at all advised to use, is much safer in version 2.0 and higher. It will *safely* unstick most of the .NET BCL blocking calls including `Thread.Sleep`, `WaitHandle.WaitOne`, `Monitor.Enter`, etc. <strike>**It is my interpretation that the meaning of suspended in this context is a thread that is blocked inside one of these calls.**</strike> I believe this can be proven with the following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = new Thread(() => 
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread blocking");
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                Console.WriteLine("Thread unblocked");
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ThreadAbortException");
            }
        });
    Console.WriteLine("Starting thread");
    thread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting 1 second");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Aborting thread");
    thread.Abort();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for thread to end");
    thread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ended");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Replace the call to `Thread.Sleep` with the other blocking calls in the BCL to see which ones can be "poked" by `Thread.Abort`.

**Update**

My original interpretation is **clearly** incorrect. The documentation almost explicity tells you what the interpretation should be.

> If Abort is called on a thread that
>   has been suspended, a
>   ThreadStateException is thrown in the
>   thread that called Abort, and
>   AbortRequested is added to the
>   ThreadState property of the thread
>   being aborted. A ThreadAbortException
>   is not thrown in the suspended thread
>   until Resume is called.

I will go ahead and leave my answer since it is tangentially relevant to the question.

Comment: I think you're interpretation is wrong. Reading the docs for `Thread.Abort`, the fact that "suspended" is used in reference to "Resume" implies that it is when in a suspended state as per the obsolete `Thread.Suspend` that the described behavior occurs.

Comment: Yep, after reading that bit a little more carefully it is indeed used in the context of `Thread.Resume`.

Comment: I decided to keep my answer since I think it does somewhat accurately answer the second part of the question. My original interpretation of the documentation was completely off...sorry to mislead.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - Abort() can throw ThreadStateException, yet the suspended thread will **still** abort when it is resumed. It's odd to get an exception from a method even though the method still performs the requested operation (albeit at some unknown point in the future). +1 for playing :)